# BasicHttpBinding using transport sercurity with Self signed Certificate

Tags: wcf, ssl, certificate

I have WCF service, using both BasicHttpBinding and NetTcpBinding at different endpoints within one ServiceHost. NetTcp is using a self signed certificate, which is loaded from file, all were well untill I try to actually make use of the BasicHttpBinding, so I do:

On server:

```
var ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(blah blah);
host.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.Certificate = GetCertificate(); //load a certificate from file
host.Credentials.ClientCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.None;
var httpBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();
httpBinding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport;
httpBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate;
```

On Client:

```
ChannelFactory.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.None;
var cer = GetCertificate();
ChannelFactory.Credentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = cer;

var httpBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();
httpBinding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport;
httpBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate;
//accept any cert
System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
                ((sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true);
```

However when connects, I got this error

> Exception - An error occurred while
>   making the HTTP request to
>   https://localhost/MyService. This
>   could be due to the fact that the
>   server certificate is not configured
>   properly with HTTP.SYS in the HTTPS
>   case. This could also be caused by a
>   mismatch of the security binding
>   between the client and the server.

certificate is not installed, and it worked fine with net tcp binding, I guess I must missed something small?

One thing I notice is net.tcp is duplex channel while basic http is simplex, I am sure there is  a difference to setup? For example, I needed to load certificate at both end for net.tcp, what happens to basic http then?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried to browse the https url in browser. Does it show the WCF help page.

Comment: No it does not, I think my certificate is not setup properly but could not find where :(

Comment: Check http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/WCFSSL.aspx if you are using a non IIS hosting. You may not have configure the certificate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Certificate for HTTPS is not configured in WCF configuration. You must configure certificate for http.sys. To do that use [netsh.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733791.aspx) from command line with elevated privileges. If you are hosting your service in IIS/WAS you don't have to use netsh and you can [configure HTTPS directly in IIS](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/144/how-to-set-up-ssl-on-iis-7/).

Comment: The reason why I load from file (actually file is in memory) is I try to avoid command line as they are "harder" than configured in code and only valid until my service shut down. There is also a problem with port sharing If I bind a certificate to a port.

Comment: @Yuan: HTTPS is provided by http.sys - it is Windows kernel driver with its own requirements. If you want to use HTTPS you must install certificate to certificate store and register it by netsh. You can do it as a custom action in the application installer.

Comment: It seems at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733791.aspx explains all, it is not very nice to setup certificate on the binding AND set setup in HTTP.SYS , you saved me a lot of time, thanks!

Comment: That last link is busted.